# Binding Storyboard to ActualHeight doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I want to expand a stack panel from a fixed height to the actual height:

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.MaxHeight)" Storyboard.TargetName="stpAbout">
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=stpAbout, Mode=OneWay}">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
</EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
```

The stack panel:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stpAbout" MaxHeight="200">
```

The code to run the storyboard:

```
var dia = new MessageDialog(stpAbout.ActualHeight.ToString());
await dia.ShowAsync(); // Shows an actual height of 312

var sbExpand = (Storyboard)Resources["stbExpandAbout"]; // Get the storyboard
sbExpand.Begin(); // Play the storyboard

dia = new MessageDialog(stpAbout.ActualHeight.ToString());
await dia.ShowAsync(); // Shows still an actual heigh of 312
```

But the stack panel doesn't expand. It collapses and has now no height at all.

before the animation

[image]

after the animation

[image]

**Sample**

Page:

```
<Page
x:Class="Juqe.Client.UWP.Pages.BlankPage1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Juqe.Client.UWP.Pages"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="stbExpand">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.MaxHeight)" Storyboard.TargetName="stpToExpand">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=stpToExpand, Mode=OneWay}">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stpToExpand" MaxHeight="96">
            <Grid Height="48" Background="Red" />
            <Grid Height="48" Background="Green" />
            <Grid Height="48" Background="Blue" />
            <Grid Height="48" Background="Yellow" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Expand</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dia = new MessageDialog(stpToExpand.ActualHeight.ToString());
    await dia.ShowAsync();

    var sbExpand = (Storyboard)Resources["stbExpand"]; // Get the storyboard
    sbExpand.Begin(); // Play the expand storyboard

    sbExpand.Completed += async (se, ev) =>
    {
        dia = new MessageDialog(stpToExpand.ActualHeight.ToString());
        await dia.ShowAsync();
    };
}
```

**"Solution"**

I manipulated the storyboard in code after getting it:

```
((storyboard.Children[0] as DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames).KeyFrames[0] as EasingDoubleKeyFrame).Value = stpAbout.ActualHeight; // Correct the storyboard
```

Comment: How can the ActualHeight be 312 if the MaxHeight is set to 200 in the first place...?

Comment: I think the MaxHeight doesn't affect the ActualHeight. I wasn't sure therefore I showed the two dialogs and it showed 312 both times.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample of your issue when asking a question. You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints and inspecting the various elements/properties of the `stpAbout` object at different points within your code execution? It might give you some better insight on which properties are being used. Maybe you are accessing something other than what you are intending.

Comment: Yes, but I can't find any reason it shouldn't work

Comment: Why is this tagged WPF if you are obviously building a UWP page?

Comment: Because bindings and storyboards are the same in WPF and UWP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding won't work here as like [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx):

> **Note**  Although it has an ActualHeightProperty backing field, ActualHeight does not raise property change notifications and it should be thought of as a regular CLR property and not a dependency property.